# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting this error

`dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic`

I have added CaptureRecord Framework. It works well in simulator. But getting this error when try to run on actual device.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this question and your comment below: I had a similar issue on Mac OS, where the deployment target of a cloned git project was 10.8, but I was running 10.7 on the machine. Your comment helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case was caused by having my Xcode target's `iOS Deployment Target` at iOS 6.1, while running on a 5.0 Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Add -fobjc-arc to your OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS in project settings

Comment: This had no effect for me. The problem for me was that I had a framework included with deployment target 6.0. After having recompiled it with deployment target 5.0, resulting in all projects and sub-projects being built with deployment target 5.0, everything worked.

Comment: @JugsteR Maybe you should move this to an answer?