# Cloning a git repo in Xcode means unit test do not run

Tags: xcode, git, unit-testing

I have worked on machine A on an Xcode project, which is linked to a bitbucket git repo. All up-to-date and committed, unit tests run fine.

Now I want to work on it on machine B. I fire up Xcode, clone the repository, and all the files are there in my project. I press cmd-U to run the unit tests, and they 'pass' in lightning speed, or rather, they do not run at all. This is the error message I get:

`objc[6434]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set

2013-06-11 10:20:05.935 otest[6434:303] The test bundle at /Users/oliver/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TextToolsSystem-celmxjqlddjrjvblrklrnvdpytux/Build/Products/Debug/TextToolsSystemTests.octest could not be loaded because a link error occurred.  It is likely that dyld cannot locate a framework framework or library that the the test bundle was linked against, possibly because the framework or library had an incorrect install path at link time.

2013-06-11 10:20:05.942 otest[6436:203] *** NSTask: Task create for path '
TextToolsSystemTests' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.`

The project does not use any additional frameworks or libraries, and works fine on machine A. A listing of the mentioned directory yields

`total 192
-rwxr-xr-x  1 oliver  staff  96604 11 Jun 10:20 TextToolsSystemTests`

and that file is a `Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`.

Machine A: MBP, OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.6.2
Machine B: MBA, OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.6.2
Building the project gives no error (it hasn't got an executable yet that could be run)

Are there any settings that I need to adjust to make it work which the cloning did not carry over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some digging I found the solution:

1. I used `otool -L` to list the required libraries that the target was referencing (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api) for reference).
2. Then I manually added in all the libraries/frameworks, even though they're CoreFoundation etc, which would normally not be required. However, it also included `libobjc.A.dylib`.
   Now I was getting a different error, `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic`, which was expected in that library.
3. I then searched for that error message, and it lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527424/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-objc-setproperty-atomic), which had no accepted answer, but in a comment stated *The problem for me was that I had a framework included with deployment target 6.0. After having recompiled it with deployment target 5.0, resulting in all projects and sub-projects being built with deployment target 5.0, everything worked.*
4. I checked the OS X deployment target, and it was set to 10.8–but machine B only runs 10.7! So I changed the target to 10.7, and then it worked.

**So, to summarise:** the issue was that the deployment target was set to an OS revision which was higher than that of the current machine. Duh!